# What type of evidence to prove continuous residence in the US for naturalization

Tags: usa, immigration, citizenship

Specifically, I am asking about the category "Your immediate family remained in the U.S." My brother and his wife remained in the US during the time I was absent. Note: I am a dependent on my brother. What evidence should I provide to prove that he was present in the US during the time I was absent? Does the following evidence count: his income taxes and W-2 tax form during the time I was absent?

Comment: Are you talking about the case where you left the US for a trip of between 6 months and 1 year, so you are presumed to have interrupted [continuous residence](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-d-chapter-3), unless you can prove otherwise?

Comment: More than a year. Yes, the question assumes that I have interrupted continuous residence. So, what type of evidence would count?

Comment: Well, if you were absent more than a year, then you have definitely interrupted continuous residence (unless you had N-470). The evidence of ties to the US would only help you qualify for naturalization at 4 years + 1 day after returning rather than 4 years + 6 months. Is that what you are trying to do?